# Перенос ссылки на след элемент цепочки из сеттера в конструктор, шаблон цепочка обязанностей

Tags: java

Как сделать чтоб ссылка на след элемент фильтрации файла передавался в главный абстарктный класс паттерна цепочка обязанностей?
Сам абстрактный класс:

```
public abstract class ChainFilter {
private ChainFilter next;

/**
 * Sets next filter.
 *
 * @param next next filter
 */
public void setNext(ChainFilter next) {
    this.next = next;
}

public boolean doFilter(File file) {
    boolean result = checkFile(file);
    if (result && next != null) {
        return next.doFilter(file);
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Checks if file is match to filter.
 * @param file file will be checked
 * @return true if the file is match
 */
protected abstract boolean checkFile(File file);
}
```

Класс-наследник, который фильтрует по имени

```
public class NameFilter extends ChainFilter {
private String fileName;

public NameFilter(String fileName) {
    if (fileName == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("No file name was entered.");
    }
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

@Override
protected boolean checkFile(File file) {
    String fileNameWithOutEx = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(file.getName());
    return fileNameWithOutEx.contains(fileName);
}
}
```

Еще есть несколько классов-фильтров.
Класс-билдер:

```
public class FilterBuilder {
private List<ChainFilter> filterList;

public FilterBuilder() {
    filterList = new ArrayList<>();
}

/**
 * Adds new filter to list of filters.
 *
 * @param newFilter new filter
 */
public void addFilter(ChainFilter newFilter) {
    filterList.add(newFilter);
}


public ChainFilter build() {
    ChainFilter filter = null;
    ChainFilter firstFilter = null;
    for (ChainFilter f : filterList) {
        if (firstFilter == null) {
            firstFilter = f;
            filter = f;
        } else {
            filter.setNext(f);
            filter = f;
        }
    }
    return firstFilter;
}
}
```

и мейн:

```
public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    FilterBuilder filter = new FilterBuilder();

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print(Questions.DIRECTORY_QUESTION);
    String dir = in.nextLine();

    FileFinder manager = new FileFinder(dir);

    aksForNameFilter(in, filter);

    if(manager.getFilteredFileList(manager.getDirPath(), filter.build()).size() == 0){
        System.out.println("Any files was found");
    } else {
        for (File temp : manager.getFilteredFileList(manager.getDirPath(), filter.build())) {
            System.out.println(temp.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("Size: " + temp.length());
        }
    }
}

private static void aksForNameFilter(Scanner scanner, FilterBuilder filter) {
    System.out.println(Questions.NAME_FILTER_QUESTION);
    if (scanner.nextLine().equals("y")) {
        System.out.println(Questions.FILE_NAME_QUESTION);
        String fileName = scanner.nextLine();
        filter.addFilter(new NameFilter(fileName));
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Дисклаймер: я не пишу на java, потому критика привествуется.

По моему вы немного все усложнили. Давайте сначала создадим интерфейс для фильтра

```
public interface IFileFilter{
    boolean IsMatch(File file);
}
```

Имея интерфейс, можно накидать операций типа логического И:

```
public class AndFileFilter implements IFileFilter {    
    private final IFileFilter first;
    private final IFileFilter second;

    public AndFileFilter(IFileFilter first, IFileFilter second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean IsMatch(File file) {
        return first.IsMatch(file) && second.IsMatch(file);
    }
}
```

Имея логическое И, можно накидать нехитрый билдер

```
public class FileFilterBuilder {
    private IFileFilter currentFilter;

    public  FileFilterBuilder(IFileFilter initial){
        currentFilter = initial;
    }

    public FileFilterBuilder(){
        this(f->true);
    }

    public void addFilter(IFileFilter filter){
        currentFilter = new AndFileFilter(currentFilter, filter);
    }

    public IFileFilter build(){
        return currentFilter;
    }
}
```

Менеджер вообще опишем одной строкой

```
public class FileManager{
    public Stream<File> getMathcingFiles(File directory, IFileFilter filter){
        return Arrays.stream(directory.listFiles()).filter(f->filter.IsMatch(f));
    }
}
```

Имея билдер и менеджер, можно уже все связать воедино

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File folder = new File("D:\\Code\\SO_Samples\\1018935\\src\\com\\company");
    FileFilterBuilder builder = new FileFilterBuilder();

    builder.addFilter(f->f.getName().startsWith("File"));

    FileManager manager = new FileManager();
    manager.getMathcingFiles(folder, builder.build())
            .forEach(f-> System.out.println(f.getName()));
}
```

ну и на выходе получаем

```
FileFilterBuilder.java
FileManager.java
```